# Suspend shortcut for Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to set the "Scroll Lock key" to be a toggle shortcut to suspend and resume
my Autohotkey script. I mean to get all the lines in a currently running ahk script suspended and resumed by a toggle shortcut.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short, precise answer is that yes, it's possible.

The long, complicated answer is to add the following line to your script

```
scrolllock:: Pause
```

Comment: Thanks hexacynaide, also thanks user3062270, but I can only put one green check.

Comment: `Pause` pauses the script's current thread. `Suspend` Disables or enables all or selected hotkeys and hotstrings.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle suspend:

```
f1::suspend
```

Close the script:

```
f2::exitapp
```

Reload the script:

```
f3::reload
```

Edit the script:

```
f4::edit
```

I find that including this speeds up editing / testing:

```
back = open the script in notepad
forward = save and exit notepad
refresh = reload

browser_back::edit
```

browser_forward::

```
send ^{s}
send !{f4}
return

browser_refresh::reload
```

add reload at bottom of browser_forward hotkey, i say having it seperate